Identification of a live action short film
I am looking for a short film made in the late 80s or early 90s which was aired on French TV channel Canal + around 1990/1992.
In my (failed) memory, the film's title was "Night Wings" but it's neither of these.
From my memory, the film featured scenes involving a bumblebee or a fly that was actually a robot and that used its tiny size to break into a building and detonate explosions and steal documents.
There were a few close-up shots on the bug/robot and lots of low-budget special effects that really entertained me (at the time!). Everything took place at night, in a very dark environment, maybe post-apocalyptic.
It was very short and maybe European.

This is a total shot in the dark, but if you're willing to push up your timeline to 1996, it might have the first part of the original LEXX miniseries.  The opening plot involves a prisoner named Thodin using a robotic "bugbomb" to fly through the building where he's being held and free him by detonating against a cable that controls his cage.  The bugbomb doesn't steal documents, but does scan data streams to find its target. The FX are definitely dated, and were low-budget to begin with. There's a pic of the bugbomb here: http://lexx.wikia.com/wiki/Thodin

@Steve-O - You should post that as an answer; The 'bug bomb' is very memorable and the effects are noticeably low-budget; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLkcV-D8hi0
